# Issues with version control for UBUNTU 20.04 and 22.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a computer that had ubuntu 20.04 installed on a Windows OS, the ubuntu 20.04 app was uninstalled, but under the Linux folder in Windows "Documents" under the Linux section there is a folder there that says ubuntu-20.04, I can't access this folder and just want to delete it, how do I go about this? When I try to access it it says

> \wsl.localhost\ubuntu-20.04 is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. Attempt to access invalid address.

I do have admin rights on the computer but just want to remove this folder completely.

`wsl -l -v` showed:

```
* Ubuntu-20.04, State: Stopped, Version: 2
```

And `wsl -version` showed:

```
WSL version: 2.1.4.0 
Kernal version: 5.15.146.1-2 
WSLg version: 1.0.60 
MSRDC version: 1.2.5105 
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511 
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22631.3235
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506698/edit) your question to include the results of `wsl -l -v` and `wsl --version` (in PowerShell)?  `wsl --version` might not return anything other than the help - If so, that's useful information as well.  Reply to me with an @ before my username in order to make sure I get notified when you do so.  Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly how you uninstalled WSL - in particular, whether you just turned off the feature, or whether you ran the `wsl --unregister` command (see for example [How do I uninstall a WSL Distribution?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#how-do-i-uninstall-a-wsl-distribution-))

Comment: @steeldriver Agreed - I'm also wondering if this might be a case of having installed (or possibly uninstalled) as an Admin user.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds fundamentally, it's a question about Windows rather than Ubuntu anyhow (although I know the community tends to give a pass to WSL issues is we feel we can help)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thank you for getting back to me, the UBUNTU windows app was uninstalled using the settings>apps>default apps on windows. `wsl -l -v` says: * Ubuntu-20.04 state: Stopped, Version: 2. `wsl --version` shows WSL version: 2.1.4.0; Kernal version: 5.15.146.1-2; WSLg version: 1.0.60; MSRDC version: 1.2.5105; Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511; DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp; Windows version: 10.0.22631.3235

Answer (score 0):

##### *Short answer (hopefully):*

As @Steeldriver mentioned in the comments, running the following command inside PowerShell should remove Ubuntu.  Please note that this is a **destructive**, irreversible operation. It will not ask for confirmation. It will remove Ubuntu and any files inside the distribution, but it sounds like this is what you intended:

```
wsl --unregister Ubuntu-20.04
```

This is based off of the `Ubuntu-20.04` in your `wsl -l -v` results in your question. Other users should confirm their distribution name using `wsl -l -v`.

I say "hopefully" because of your permission-denied error.  That says that something *else* is wrong behind the scenes, but I'm hoping that uninstalling/unregistering will still be successful.

##### *Explanation:*

You can see my answer on Super User for how to [Completely Uninstall/Reinstall WSL](https://superuser.com/a/1755410/1210833), but even *just* uninstalling Ubuntu (or any distribution) from WSL requires at least two steps.

When you install Ubuntu into WSL from the Microsoft Store, two things happen:

1. First the "App", which is actually a WSL Distro Launcher ([link to reference implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL-DistroLauncher)), is installed.
2. Then the App/Distro Launcher runs, *creates your distribution*, asks for your username/password, creates your regular user, etc.

Both of these must be removed separately.

There was a time when uninstalling the App would remove both, but this was problematic, because the App Uninstall screen in Windows says, *"Your documents will not be affected"*.  Of course, this led to some unexpected data loss.

So the App/Distro Launcher uninstall was changed to *only* uninstall that portion.

As a result, you do have to run the `--unregister` steps separately to actually remove the *distribution*, which includes your documents and data that you've created in WSL/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using `wsl --unregister Ubuntu-20.04`, next problem I had was all the files were on the system still taking up memory, which is why they wanted to uninstall Ubuntu in the first place. I then turned off the WSL for linux on windows system, did the reboot. The memory was still full. I downloaded FileLight and removed all Ubuntu files, now all is working well and removed from the memory. Thank you to everyone, especially @NotTheDr01ds!I really appreciate the help you all gave me!